# Numba function fails when imported from another script, but works well when compiled manually

Tags: python, numba

Here is a reproducible example. The numba function "is_in_set_pnb" doesn't work when is imported from "functions.py" script. **However, it works just fine when is defined in the same script.**

### functions.py script

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import pandas as pd

# corrFilter function
def corrFilter(df, threshold):
    corr_matrix = df.corr().abs()
    flat_matrix = (corr_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_matrix.shape), k=1).astype(np.bool))
                 .stack()
                 .sort_values(ascending=False))
    flat_matrix = pd.DataFrame(flat_matrix).reset_index()
    flat_matrix.columns=["var1", "var2", "correlation"]
    flat_matrix = flat_matrix.reindex(flat_matrix.correlation.sort_values(ascending=False).index).reset_index().drop(["index"],axis=1)
    filtered_matrix = flat_matrix[flat_matrix.correlation > threshold]
    pairs_to_remove = filtered_matrix[["var1", "var2"]].to_numpy()
    
    return pairs_to_remove

# Numba function / numpy.isin() improved version
@nb.jit(parallel=True)
def is_in_set_pnb(a, b):
    shape = a.shape
    a = a.ravel()
    n = len(a)
    result = np.full(n, False)
    set_b = set(b)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        if a[i] in set_b:
            result[i] = True
    return result.reshape(shape)
```

---

### main.py script

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
from functions import *

# Loading data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
data = iris.data
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data.columns = ["var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"]

# Get pairs with a correlation higher than 0.5
remove_pairs = corrFilter(data, 0.5)
remove_pairs_check = np.sum(remove_pairs, axis=1)
# Remove triplets with pairs with a higher correlation than 0.5
triplets = [list(k) for k in itertools.combinations(data.columns, 3)]
array_triplets = np.vstack(triplets).astype(object)
n, d = array_triplets.shape
pair1 = np.sum(array_triplets[:,[0,1]], axis=1).reshape(n, 1)
pair2 = np.sum(array_triplets[:,[1,2]], axis=1).reshape(n, 1)
pair3 = np.sum(array_triplets[:,[0,2]], axis=1).reshape(n, 1)
array_triplets_check = np.concatenate((pair1, pair2, pair3), axis =1)

# Check if each pair is in the remove_pairs_check list
array_triplets_check_v1 = np.in1d(array_triplets_check, remove_pairs_check).reshape(n, d)
# Using numba function from "functions.py" script"
# This fails!!
array_triplets_check_v2 = is_in_set_pnb(array_triplets_check, remove_pairs_check)
```

### However, if we define the numba function within the main.py script:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.jit(parallel=True)
def is_in_set_pnb(a, b):
    shape = a.shape
    a = a.ravel()
    n = len(a)
    result = np.full(n, False)
    set_b = set(b)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        if a[i] in set_b:
            result[i] = True
    return result.reshape(shape)

# This works properly!!!
array_triplets_check_v2 = is_in_set_pnb(array_triplets_check, remove_pairs_check)
```

What I am missing?? I am using:

```
numba                     0.50.1           py38h47e9c7a_0
```

Comment: Don't use `from foo import *` if possible; it makes a mess of your namespace

Comment: Thank you! I will consider it next time.